# Get Size of Bounding Box Around Multiple Objects

Tags: objects, measurement

Today I'm playing with models downloaded from Thingverse. Some of these models have many parts. When I load all the parts into Blender and arrange them in some way, I would like to be able to select them and get the size of the bounding box that surrounds all of them. I could probably whip something up in Python, but surely Blender has a built-in method?

This is a duplicate of [Properties of a selection of objects](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/14072/properties-of-a-selection-of-objects) but that question is six years old and perhaps something has changed since then.

Answer (score 4):

User @sambler provided a script on the linked question, but I found it had bit-rotted in the change to Blender 2.8/2.9

This version worked for me under Blender 2.9.2:

```
import bpy
import bmesh
from bpy.props import BoolProperty, FloatVectorProperty
import mathutils
from bpy_extras import object_utils

# from blender templates
def add_box(width, height, depth):
    """
    This function takes inputs and returns vertex and face arrays.
    no actual mesh data creation is done here.
    """

    verts = [(+1.0, +1.0, -1.0),
             (+1.0, -1.0, -1.0),
             (-1.0, -1.0, -1.0),
             (-1.0, +1.0, -1.0),
             (+1.0, +1.0, +1.0),
             (+1.0, -1.0, +1.0),
             (-1.0, -1.0, +1.0),
             (-1.0, +1.0, +1.0),
             ]

    faces = [(0, 1, 2, 3),
             (4, 7, 6, 5),
             (0, 4, 5, 1),
             (1, 5, 6, 2),
             (2, 6, 7, 3),
             (4, 0, 3, 7),
            ]

    # apply size
    for i, v in enumerate(verts):
        verts[i] = v[0] * width, v[1] * depth, v[2] * height

    return verts, faces

def group_bounding_box():
    minx, miny, minz = (999999.0,)*3
    maxx, maxy, maxz = (-999999.0,)*3
    location = [0.0,]*3
    for obj in bpy.context.selected_objects:
        for v in obj.bound_box:
            v_world = obj.matrix_world @ mathutils.Vector((v[0],v[1],v[2]))

            if v_world[0] < minx:
                minx = v_world[0]
            if v_world[0] > maxx:
                maxx = v_world[0]

            if v_world[1] < miny:
                miny = v_world[1]
            if v_world[1] > maxy:
                maxy = v_world[1]

            if v_world[2] < minz:
                minz = v_world[2]
            if v_world[2] > maxz:
                maxz = v_world[2]

    verts_loc, faces = add_box((maxx-minx)/2, (maxz-minz)/2, (maxy-miny)/2)
    mesh = bpy.data.meshes.new("BoundingBox")
    bm = bmesh.new()
    for v_co in verts_loc:
        bm.verts.new(v_co)

    bm.verts.ensure_lookup_table()

    for f_idx in faces:
        bm.faces.new([bm.verts[i] for i in f_idx])

    bm.to_mesh(mesh)
    mesh.update()
    location[0] = minx+((maxx-minx)/2)
    location[1] = miny+((maxy-miny)/2)
    location[2] = minz+((maxz-minz)/2)
    bbox = object_utils.object_data_add(bpy.context, mesh, operator=None)
    # does a bounding box need to display more than the bounds??
    bbox.location = location
    bbox.display_type = 'BOUNDS'
    bbox.hide_render = True

group_bounding_box()
```

something

Comment: See https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/218849/15543 can add a cube display type empty instead of an non rendering wire display type mesh.

Comment: Can this script calculate objects AABB under specific collection?

Comment: @WinertozBotawar I don't quite understand your question? If I remember correctly, this script works on all selected objects so if you select all objects under a specific collection it should work?

Comment: Yes it works. Just need to select all objects under a collection.